# Select the nth row in SQL server using TOP and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the nth row from a table. I understand how to do this but it is not working correctly.

What I have tried: Currently I select the top 6 with it being ordered in asc order. Then I select the top 1 in desc order. This should give me the 6th instance.

What keeps happening: No matter what I do I always get the first instance. I can change the "top 6" and change the asc and desc or order and I always get the first instance.

This is not the full code, it involves a UNION and makes it difficult to use row_number(). Because I need the cross apply it makes CTE difficult. Does anyone see something I am obviously doing wrong?

```
update t2
set RWK3_OPERATION_CODE = (select top 1 t3.OPERATION_CODE)       

From plant.PIECE_DETAIL t2
full join app.OHCMS_TRACE_SN_XREF t4
on t2.TRACE_ID = t4.TRACE_ID
cross apply
(Select top 1 * from 
     (Select top 6 * from (
               Select
                      t1.TRACE_ID
                     ,t1.OPERATION_CODE
                     ,t1.OPERATION_START_DATE_D 
                     ,t1.OPERATION_START_TIME
              from app.OHCMS_ITEM_OPERATION_TRACE t1
              where t1.TRACE_ID = t2.TRACE_ID
              )as t5 
              order by (OPERATION_START_DATE_D), (OPERATION_START_TIME) 
    )as t6
    order by (OPERATION_START_DATE_D), (OPERATION_START_TIME) desc
)as t3

Where t2.rwk_cycle > 10
```

Comment: To make it work you have to add DESC to `OPERATION_START_TIME`. `order by (OPERATION_START_DATE_D), (OPERATION_START_TIME) DESC ` in the line after `as t5`

Comment: To get the exact opposite order, you need to add desc to both order by arguments: `order by (OPERATION_START_DATE_D) desc, (OPERATION_START_TIME) desc`

Comment: Hello again, As I say before post a sample data and desire output. That way will be easy to give you an answer.

Comment: What version of SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each portion of your `ORDER BY` will default to `ASC` unless you override with an explicit `DESC`.

In your line...

```
order by (OPERATION_START_DATE_D), (OPERATION_START_TIME) desc
```

...it is treating it the same as if you typed...

```
order by (OPERATION_START_DATE_D) ASC, (OPERATION_START_TIME) desc
```

You want...

```
order by (OPERATION_START_DATE_D) DESC, (OPERATION_START_TIME) desc
```

Here's the full query (just a copy and paste of your original with the corrected `ORDER BY`)

```
update t2
set RWK3_OPERATION_CODE = (select top 1 t3.OPERATION_CODE)       

From plant.PIECE_DETAIL t2
full join app.OHCMS_TRACE_SN_XREF t4
on t2.TRACE_ID = t4.TRACE_ID
cross apply
(Select top 1 * from 
     (Select top 6 * from (
               Select
                      t1.TRACE_ID
                     ,t1.OPERATION_CODE
                     ,t1.OPERATION_START_DATE_D 
                     ,t1.OPERATION_START_TIME
              from app.OHCMS_ITEM_OPERATION_TRACE t1
              where t1.TRACE_ID = t2.TRACE_ID
              )as t5 
              order by (OPERATION_START_DATE_D), (OPERATION_START_TIME) 
    )as t6
    order by 
      (OPERATION_START_DATE_D) DESC, 
      (OPERATION_START_TIME) desc
)as t3
Where t2.rwk_cycle > 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into the [row_number() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)? It would provide an alternative path to finding the 6th value in an ordered result set. It basically gives each row a number, and when combined with a sort clause, allows you to specify a particular value for the row number in the where clause. General form would be something like this:

```
Select subTable.* 
From (Select a.a, row_number() Over(Order by a.b desc) as orderedRow
    From a) as subTable
Where subTable.orderedRow = 6
```

Edit: I should also mention that this only works in SQL Server 2005 and up - not SQL Server 2000, and that it is not present in all database platforms.

Comment: I agree with ROW_NUMBER but your example here won't work. You can't reference orderedRow in the same query. It would need to either be a subquery to get the RowNumber or a cte.

Comment: Good catch, forgot about that. Edited original answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY key ASC) AS rownumber,
    columns
  FROM tablename
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber <= n
```